# Adding data to database from grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having some trouble picking up IDs from my grid view in order to add them into my database. I am getting a does not exist error in my.cs file when the ID exists in the grid view it seem to be not able to pick it up.

```
    myConnection.Open();


    GridView1.Visible = true;
    string IDdata = Session["userID"].ToString();
    string OwnerData = txtprojectOwner.Text;
    string MasterData = txtScrumMaster.Text;
    string devData = userName.Text;
```

Heres the code I'm having trouble with in my .cs file the userName.Text isn't being picked up and its throwing the error

```
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="userName" Name="userName"PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
```

Heres the code from inside the list view from the item I'm trying to add into the database. Any help with tis would be appreciated.

Comment: Means on button click event , all list data will be insert into database ?

Comment: I only want the username from the list data to be inserted not all the data thats being displayed

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access control like that if your control is in Grid View .

You have to find control from Grid view and after you can access it and you can

get text value of that control .

In Button click event, you can find each rows textbox value and you

can insert into database .

```
   foreach(GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows) {
if(row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) {
    TextBox TextBoxfname = row.FindControl("TextBox1") as TextBox ;
    string txtname= TextBoxfname.Text ;// You can insert txtname into database .
}
```

}

GridView1 : ID of gridview

TextBox1 : ID of Textbox

Let me know , if you will be stuck .

Thanks .

Comment: Thanks for your help although this gives me an error for Row it says theres no definition.

Comment: Do I need to change TextBoxID to userName? or am I trying to find something else? Thanks

Comment: In place of TextBoxID you need to add ID of textbox .

Comment: I'm having trouble referencing the text box I want, the grid view is being populated from a search and the text box the search is coming from the id is textbox1 meaning the control Id needs to be textbox1 for all the text boxes in the grid view if I'm correct. This makes it difficult to uniquely reference a specific textbox from the gridview.

Comment: you can bind hiddenfield near textbox with unique key .and after you can find that hidden field accordingly Textbox and specify that textbox .

Comment: how would I go about doing that sorry I've never used hidden fields before